# Appending at specific place in XML with c#

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

I've a XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MY_COMPUTER>
    <HARDWARE uid="" update="" functions=""  />
    <SOFTWARE>
        <GAMES uid="" update="" functions=""  url="">
            <GAME1 Game1-Attribute1="" />
            <GAME2 Game2-Attribute1="" Game2-Attribute2="" Game2-Attribute3="" Game2-Attribute4="" />
            <GAME3 Game3-Attribute1="" Game3-Attribute2="" Game3-Attribute3=""/>
            <GAME4 Game4-Attribute1="" Game4-Attribute2=""/>
        </GAMES>
    </SOFTWARE>
</MY_COMPUTER>
```

I'm trying to add new software types into this xml file for example browsers, browser will be same as game, it will have browser1, browser2 and a few of browsers will have attributes. I've used this

```
string filePath = "test.xml";

            XElement root = XElement.Load(filePath, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
 root.Add(
                        new XElement("BROWSER",
                        new XAttribute("uid",""), new XAttribute("update", ""),
                            new XElement("BROWSER2"),
                            new XElement("BROWSER3"),
                            new XElement("BROWSER4"), 
                            )
                            );

root.Save(filePath, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

but with this code its appending this under SOFTWARE, I know I probably made a really big beginner mistake but I couldn't fix it, can someone help me? I've also checked a lot of questions about this on stackoverflow but I still couldn't manage it. People say there are many ways like using LINQ or stream I don't know which one to use but this file wont be really huge so I just need a way that will work
Thanks

Comment: so where u want to add Browser?

Comment: What do you expect and what do you actually get?

Comment: I want to add a new browser tab under software and this browser tab will have a new group of broswer1, browser2 and so go on. With my current code its adding browser under the SOFTWARE tag so its working wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this xml piece adding after software element is that you are adding it to a `root` element itself (`root.Add`).

If you want to add it inside the software element, you should modify your code accordingly.

Find required element and invoke its `Add` method instead.

```
var softwareElement = root.Descendants("SOFTWARE").First();

softwareElement.Add(
    new XElement("BROWSER",
        new XAttribute("uid", ""), new XAttribute("update", ""),
        new XElement("BROWSER2"),
        new XElement("BROWSER3"),
        new XElement("BROWSER4")
    )
);
```

Then save all the xml as previously.

```
root.Save(filePath, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, It's working as I want now, can I ask you 1 more thing? I use xmlwriter to save the file at the first place but I dont know how to go underline after each tag so the file is so hard to read when I open and want to check, is there any command to do it?

Comment: @ShinoLexTazy Your output is not formatted nicely because of `SaveOptions.DisableFormatting` tweak. You could try to remove `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` as well, to see proper tabulation and line feeds in the output.

Comment: my XMLcreation method is like this:

 XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlWriterSettings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
            using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("test.xml", xmlWriterSettings))
            {
//my stuff
}

But still when I create it the xml file looks like a mess have to open the file and put enter's to check if its right

Comment: after removing the LoadOptions and SaveOptions its appending correctly but when I dont use the append method and only use my creation method its still a mess, but it's okay since I'll append a lot of times to the file it will be okay if its ordering it after my append

Comment: @ShinoLexTazy Try to play with `XmlWriterSettings` object. Use a default one for start and make modifications one by one. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.indent(v=vs.110).aspx) one for example.